# David’s friendly demeanour, brilliant sense of humour and warmth, "make" or "makes" you feel right at home.

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, coordinating-conjunctions

Should I use *make* or *makes* in the following sentence?

> David’s friendly demeanour, brilliant sense of humour and warmth, make you feel right at home.

I say *make,* but my friend says *makes.*

Answer (score 1):

"David’s friendly demeanour, brilliant sense of humour and warmth" is a [compound subject](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/sentences/15-sentences-using-compound-subjects-and-compound-verbs.html). In this case, "and" is the co-ordinating conjunction. When a compound subject is joined by "and", you use the plural form of the verb, therefore *make* is correct.

However, if you had used "or" or "nor", then the verb matches the subject closest to it, which would be "warmth" (singular), and *makes* would be correct:

> Neither David’s friendly demeanour, brilliant sense of humour nor warmth, makes you feel uncomfortable.

Comment: Thank You!  Tgis is what I tried to explain in a less technical or eloquent way!  Much obliged